# Can I repost the question I was suspended for?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Should I repost [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/67055/25395) without the inappropriate content? Or is editing and requesting undeletion the way to go? Editing that question would invalidate its answer.

Comment: You can edit deleted posts.

Comment: @Mithrandir Doing that would invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators won't undelete the original so you can edit.
Nor would they have to: even though it's deleted, it wasn't *self-deleted*, so you could still edit it to get it to a state where it was suitable for undeletion.
But I suspect any edit sufficient to salvage that question would turn it into a new question entirely and invalidate the existing answer.

If you think you can salvage an appropriate puzzle out of the original, you're really making a new puzzle, so post it as such.  I'll note that the original was deleted because it was a trivial puzzle that looked like nothing more than a pretext to post the inappropriate content; I'd strongly caution you to ensure its refit is much less "edgy" and much more "puzzle".